# Javascript define variables with names from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, variables, multidimensional-array

I have a function where several values from a multidimensional array are called very often, like `array[idx][3]`.. In order to save space I want to define variables with these values at the beginning of the function like so:

```
var na = array[idx][1];
var sc = array[idx][2];
...
```

I thought it would be faster if it was possible to create an array of variable names -> `var tmp = ['na','sc',...];`, create a for loop and cycle through the array of names and the multidimensional `array`, i.e.:

```
for(i = 0; i = 7, i++){

var tmp[i] = array[idx][i];

}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible - looks like you have the right code, what's wrong / what's the question?

Comment: Is it something that can't be easily tested? Somehow you're overwriting the `['na', 'sc'...]` in that for-loop.

Comment: I don't know, look here http://jsfiddle.net/dmyyaqe9/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `array` to store keys.
2. Then use `Object` to create a key-> value mapping.
3. Then use either `obj.key`(if key is fixed) or `obj[key]`(if key is a calculated value) top get the value.
4. In your jsfiddle `for (i = 0; i = 7; i++) {` will hang the browser, you should use `i < 7` instead of `i = 7`.

```js
var keys = ['na', 'sc', 'kd', 'wi', 'ki', 'de', 'sh', 'ti'];
var values = {};

var i, key, len;
// Prevent using magic number 7, get the length from the keys.
for (i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
  values[keys[i]] = i;
}
alert(values.na);
```

Its possible to further shorten the works by [Array.prototype.forEach](http://Array.prototype.forEach()):

```
// Create map store.
var v = {};
// Loop through the array
['na', 'sc', 'kd', 'wi', 'ki', 'de', 'sh', 'ti'].forEach(function(key, idx) {
    v[key] = idx;
});
alert(v.na);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmyyaqe9/4/)

Combine with your idx may be dynamic, you can create a function, given the `idx` and target array, return the object with the keys.

```js
// A list to simulate what you mentioned with array[idx][i].
var demoList = [
    ['na - 0', 'sc - 0', 'kd - 0', 'wi - 0', 'ki - 0', 'de - 0', 'sh - 0', 'ti - 0'],
    ['na - 1', 'sc - 1', 'kd - 1', 'wi - 1', 'ki - 1', 'de - 1', 'sh - 1', 'ti - 1'],
    ['na - 2', 'sc - 2', 'kd - 2', 'wi - 2', 'ki - 2', 'de - 2', 'sh - 2', 'ti - 2'],
    ['na - 3', 'sc - 3', 'kd - 3', 'wi - 3', 'ki - 3', 'de - 3', 'sh - 3', 'ti - 3'],
    ['na - 4', 'sc - 4', 'kd - 4', 'wi - 4', 'ki - 4', 'de - 4', 'sh - 4', 'ti - 4'],
    ['na - 5', 'sc - 5', 'kd - 5', 'wi - 5', 'ki - 5', 'de - 5', 'sh - 5', 'ti - 5'],
    ['na - 6', 'sc - 6', 'kd - 6', 'wi - 6', 'ki - 6', 'de - 6', 'sh - 6', 'ti - 6'],
    ['na - 7', 'sc - 7', 'kd - 7', 'wi - 7', 'ki - 7', 'de - 7', 'sh - 7', 'ti - 7']
];

var getResult = function(idx, array) {
    var v = {};
    // Only create the mapping if input array and array[idx] are both array.
    if (Array.isArray(array) && Array.isArray(array[idx])) {
        ['na', 'sc', 'kd', 'wi', 'ki', 'de', 'sh', 'ti'].forEach(function(key, i) {
            v[key] = array[idx][i];
        });
    }
    return v;
};

var v = getResult(1, demoList);
alert(v.na);
```

Comment: Well that's not exactly what i wanted, but i could use i.e. v.na, that's shorter. But it's the same length as an array like v[2], would be easier to define also. Other suggestions?

Comment: I'd like to know more precise about what you wanted. values is just a name so it's ok to change to anything you want if its valid. What do you mean 'it's the same length as an array like v[2]'.